# use one member function to calculate the height of a binary tree in C++

Tags: c++, tree

Here is the code for calculating the height of a binary tree. We assume all the node values are positive int. I used the recursion of `height` function. Is it possible to combine the member functions `int height()` and  `int height(TreeNode* root)` into one function? It is easy to implement for one dimension case (linked list), but I have no idea for Tree.

```
    struct TreeNode
    {
        int val = 0;
        TreeNode *left = NULL;
        TreeNode *right = NULL;
        TreeNode(int val): val(val){}
    };

    struct BinaryTree
    {
        TreeNode *root;
        BinaryTree(TreeNode *root) : root(root) {}

        int height() {
            return height(root);
        }

        int height(TreeNode* root) {
            if (!root)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int lheight = height(root->left);
                int rheight = height(root->right);

                return lheight > rheight ? lheight + 1 : rheight + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you have is the right way to do it.  Is there a reason you want only a single function?

Comment: @NathanOliver. I'm not entirley convinced this is right. This is a (not tail callable) recursive function running on a binary tree which seemingly doens't have to be balanced. Its very likely that this function will overflow the stack in some use cases. Turning recursive to iterative seems like a good thing to do. (And thats how I read what his question is actually asking, but its unclear)

Comment: @MikeVine That's not really what OP is asking... Combining both `height()` and `height(TreeNode* root)` into a single function will not make it tail recursive, nor iterative.

Comment: @MikeVine By right way, I mean right way to do it this way.  Whether or not recursion should be used at all is a different question.

Comment: What exactly is "right" about using a method that does not use *any* of the information within its object (which is the case with the second version of `height`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for; it just uses the method for computing a tree's own height on the subtrees, as opposed to calling a method to compute an *arbitrary* tree's height on the subtrees.

```
int height() {
    if (!root)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int lheight = root->left  ? root->left.height()  : 0;
        int rheight = root->right ? root->right.height() : 0;
        return lheight > rheight ? lheight + 1 : rheight + 1;
    }
}
```

*Update*: As @Gupta points out, `TreeNode` does not have a `height` method.  I would argue that it *should*, but that doesn't make this solution any less incorrect.

Here's a version that can be added to `TreeNode`:

```
int height() {
    int lheight = left ? left.height() : 0;
    int rheight = right ? ight.height() : 0;
    return std::max(lheight, rheight) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Small suggestion: `return std::max(lheight, rheight) + 1`

Comment: But `TreeNode` does not have a `height()` method.

Comment: for `root->left.height()`, I have the error `TreeNode* BinaryTree::root expression must have class type`

Comment: @user6703592 This is what I mentioned. You should move `height()` method to your `TreeNode` struct.

Answer (score 2):

Answering question on its face value. Following code will combine two overloads of `height` into one:

```
class BinaryTree {
    inline static const TreeNode sentinel;
...
public:
int height(const TreeNode* root_in = &sentinel) const {
    if (root_in == &sentinel)
        return height(root); 

    if (!root_in)
        return 0;

    int lheight = height(root_in->left);
    int rheight = height(root_in->right);

    return std::max(lheight, rheight) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's less succinct, you can re-write the method to be iterative using an explicit stack:

```
int height() {
    std::stack<std::pair<TreeNode *, int> > node_stack;
    node_stack.push(std::make_pair(root, 1));
    int height = 0;

    while (!node_stack.empty()) {
        auto node = node_stack.top();
        node_stack.pop();

        if (node.first) {
            height = std::max(height, node.second);
            node_stack.push(std::make_pair(node.first->left, node.second + 1));
            node_stack.push(std::make_pair(node.first->right, node.second + 1));
        }
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: TBH this code is the right code as it remvoed the recursion.. And it answers the question. +1